# Jest tests do not show timings for individual tests at random

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

Jest does not show the timings for each individual test. It will leave some out at random. Here is an example of a test run (in watch mode).

[image]

Now if I run this again, I get this result:

[image]

You can see how the timings for each individual test sometimes shows, sometimes it doesnt. What drives this? And how can i make it show timings for every test always?

Here is my jest config inside `package.json`

```json
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
```

Comment: Same here! I'm guessing/hoping those tests took <1 ms? Did you ever come to a conclusion? The `--verbose` option below did not help, though it shows some of the setup steps run in `0 ms`. So maybe if a test also runs in `0 ms`, Jest just leaves off the timing? Seems a bit weird, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by the reporter used by Jest (e.g `default`, `jest-junit`). Using the default reporter, you can get the timings for all tests using `jest --verbose`.

EDIT:

It looks like you might be using a custom reporter, and `slowTestThreshold` and colors might be overridden in your project. The default is 5 seconds, according to https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/e7edb75f8357090714213f252c5aaaa9b3c29f5f/packages/jest-config/src/Defaults.ts#L64 .

Comment: I am using most defaults as far as reporters go. Verbose mode is enabled. I've added my config to the answer for more info.